# assign multiple inputs values with same names to other hidden input

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on two forms. what i am basically doing is i get the values from one form and assign it to another form input field. the second form have all fields hidden becuase i need it for just to save all the select and assinged data and then with a submit button i will submit that hidden form and get all the values in $_post

let me clear it more below are the tr's that contain the data i am assigning to hidden form.

```
  <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="name" id="spocName"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="name" id="spocName"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="name" id="spocName"></td>
  </tr>
  .
  . 
  .
```

what basically happening with these tr's is when page load there is only on tr but user have a button to add more rows and on every click he can add one new row up to any number of rows and once he fill the name field and then press save button the input data is assigned to the input field in hidden form(second form).

```
  $(elemnt).each(function(index, element) {         
        $('#spc-name').val($("#spocName").val());
    });
```

in the above code $('#spc-name') is the id of input field in hidden form and $("#spocName") is the id of input field in first form. once value is assigned user have an other button for submit the hidden form. once form submits it save the data in db but here i am now discussing the issue and the issue is that all i did is working fine for single tr but i need a generic code so that i could insert multiple records in db.

when I print_r $_post i got this though i enter multiple records but I got this only the firs one

```
  Array
 (    
    [spc-name] => one    
 )
```

but what i was expecting is

```
Array
(    
    [0] => Array
    (    
    [spc-name] => one    
    )
    [1] => Array
    (    
    [spc-name] => two    
    )
    [2] => Array
    (    
    [spc-name] => three    
    )
    . 
    .
    . 
    .      

 )
```

I don't know where to change my code or if need of loop where to put it. So guys i need your help

I tried my best to explain it but if its still not clear I can edit my question so that my question get more clear. thanx in advance

Comment: A golden rule - DON'T use 2 DOM elements with the same id. If you do, you will get some error sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

Use name as array like this.

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" id="spocName">
```

Also dont try to give same id for multiple elements.Id must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays like below.

```
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="names[]" class="spocName"></td>
</tr>
```

With javascript, you add more rows, but all names will be `names[]`. After you submit your form, in PHP, you will do the following:

```
<?php
$names = $_POST['names'];
foreach($names as $name){
   echo $name;
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Note: You should use `CLASS` and not `ID` if you have multiple elements using the same name.

Using jQuery, do the following:

```
$('.spocName').each(function(){
    //get the value of the table row field
    var formValue = $(this).val();
    //now, create a new hidden input
    var hiddenForm = '<input type="hidden" name="hiddenNames[]" value="'+formValue+'">';
    //append the new hidden input to your hidden form
    $('div#hiddenForm').append(hiddenForm);
});
```

The above assumes that you have a `DIV` with an ID `hiddenForm` inside which you have your hidden input fields.

Comment: u post the first form directly but i mentioned that first form will just send values to hidden form and hidden form will then submit the values

this is hidden one <input id="spc-name"   type="hidden" value="" name="spc-name" />

Comment: Updated the answer for the hidden input form.